# Limit $\lim_{x\to 1} {\left((1 + 3x) \over (1 + 4x^2 + 3x^4)\right)}^3$

Tags: limits

Evaluate the Limit:

$$\lim_{x\to 1}  {\left((1 + 3x) \over (1 + 4x^2 + 3x^4)\right)}^3$$

The answer is supposed to be $1/8$ but i keep getting $7/23$. What did I do wrong? My work is shown below.

Step 1) $\dfrac{\lim1^3 + (3\lim x)^3}{(\lim1 + (4\lim x^2)^3 + (3\lim x^4)^3}$ Sum, Quotient Laws

Step 2) $\dfrac{1 + 27(1)}{1 + 64(1) + 27(1)}$

Step 3) $\dfrac{28}{92}$

Step 4) $\dfrac{7}{23}$

Comment: Try `Limit[((1 + 3 x)/(1 + 4 x^2 + 3 x^4))^3, x -> 1]` this gives 1/8

Comment: $(a + b)^3 \ne (a^3 + b^3)$ ...

Comment: Is the function $ \ \left( \frac{1 + 3x}{1 + 4x^2 + 3x^4} \right)^3 \ $ ?  If so, check your arithmetic -- this limit can be evaluated by direct substitution, since the function _is_ defined at $ \ x = 1 \ $ .  With the other comments that are up now, **Martin R**'s is particularly significant: you don't "cube" the coefficients _first_, but rather calculate the ratio as it stands and then cube the whole thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main error is that you replaced
$$
{\left(1 + 3x \over 1 + 4x^2 + 3x^4\right)}^3
$$
by
$$
1^3 + (3x)^3 \over 1^3 + (4x^2)^3 + (3x^4)^3
$$
which is wrong, as generally $(a+b)^3 \ne a^3 + b^3$.

As already mentioned in the comments,
$$
f(x) = {\left(1 + 3x \over 1 + 4x^2 + 3x^4\right)}^3
$$
is *continuous* at $x = 1$, therefore the limit is
$$
 \lim_{x \to 1} \, f(x) = f(1) = {\left(4 \over 8\right)}^3
= {\left(1 \over 2\right)}^3 = \frac 18 \quad .
$$

Answer (score 1):

What I did is I took the limit of what was inside of the parenthesis. I ignored the exponent at first. This yields (4/8) after taking the limit as x goes to 1.

Then taking (4/8)^3, I got 1/8.

Answer (score 0):

Use WolframAlpha command in Mathematica for a step-by-step solution (or go to Wolfram|Alpha at http://www.wolframalpha.com)

```
WolframAlpha["limit ((1+3x)/(1+4x^2+3x^4))^3 as x-> 1", {{"Limit", 2}, 
  "Content"}, PodStates -> {"Limit__Step-by-step solution"}]
```

[image]